# When saving XSSFWorkbook only one row updates

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm working on a program which reads from an Excel Spreadsheet each row and cell and then takes the data from each cell of the specific row and makes a web-service call with that data.  Once I get the return of the Web-Service XML response I parse it for a success boolean value and a message if a failure occurs.

I'm able to parse the data and I'm grabbing each rows response but when trying to edit that rows last two cells it only updates the first rows Success and Result Message cell.

Below are some snippets of my code:

```
private static XSSFRow[] retrieveRows(XSSFWorkbook wb)
{
    XSSFSheet xslSheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow[] sheetRows = new XSSFRow[xslSheet.getLastRowNum()];

    for (int i = 1; i < xslSheet.getLastRowNum()+1; i++)
    {
        sheetRows[i-1] = xslSheet.getRow(i);
    }

    return sheetRows;
}

public static String[] processRow(XSSFRow xslRow)
{
    String[] cellValues = new String[totalCells];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalCells; i++)
    {
        XSSFCell currentCell = xslRow.getCell(i);
        String cellVal;
        try
        {
            cellVal = currentCell.getStringCellValue();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cellVal = "";
        }
        cellValues[i] = cellVal;
        System.out.println("Cell "+i+": "+cellVal);
    }

    return cellValues;
}
```

And the final portion where all the magic happens ... or something like that.

```
try
    {
        XSSFRow[] xslRows = retrieveRows(theWorkbook);
        ArrayList<String[]> rowCellVals = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String sessionKey[] = WQSServices.sessionToken();

        for (int r = 0; r < xslRows.length; r++)
        {               
            System.out.println("R Value: "+r);
            rowCellVals.add(processRow(xslRows[r]));

            if(sessionKey[0].equals("true"))
            {
                String sessionData = sessionKey[1];
                String[] cellValCurrRow = rowCellVals.get(r);
                String attachmentData[] = WQSServices.uploadAttachment(sessionData, cellValCurrRow);

                XSSFCell cell = xslRows[r].getCell(7);

                if(cell == null)
                {
                    cell = xslRows[r].createCell(7);
                }

                XSSFCell cell2 = xslRows[r].getCell(8);

                if(cell2 == null)
                {
                    cell2 = xslRows[r].createCell(8);
                }

                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell2.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(attachmentData[0]);
                cell2.setCellValue(attachmentData[1]);

                System.out.println("New Cell Data: 1-"+cell.getStringCellValue()+" 2-"+cell2.getStringCellValue());

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(xslFile);
                theWorkbook.write(fos);
                fos.close();
            }
            else
            {                   

                XSSFCell cell = xslRows[r].getCell(7);

                if(cell == null)
                {
                    cell = xslRows[r].createCell(7);
                }

                System.out.println("The Cell: "+cell.getStringCellValue());

                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(sessionKey[0]);

                FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(xslFile);
                theWorkbook.write(fis);
                fis.close();

            }

            readFile();
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You appear to be writing out the file from *inside* the forloop, shouldn't that be outside at the end?

Comment: Thanks, my brain was fried.  Appreciate the quick assessment and simple answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Gagravarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685641/gagravarr/) observation my issue was based on having my file output stream within the for loop.  Once I moved this out of the for loop everything wrote to the workbook as expected.